# Machine learning: beginner study material.

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, machine-learning

Can anyone suggest to me some beginner study material for Machine learning applications in fields of

1) Financial forecasting and

2) Online advertisement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably not, because machine learning used in these fields is just machine learning applied to domain specific models. In general, understanding X technique in Y field requires independent fundamental understanding of both the field Y and the technique X. As a result, since there are so many combinations of X and Y, there are unlikely to be comprehensive beginner resources for any given combination. You might find beginner resources for X and Y individually.

Answer (score 0):

The topic is very broad. One can do many different analysis on financial forcasting and advertisement. You may want to take a look at : 
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13937/which-machine-learning-algorithms-can-be-used-for-time-series-forecasts

Answer (score 0):

For financial analysis, besides common machine learning techniques, you will benefit from the knowledge of time series.

There is a good online book called [Time Series Analysis and Its Applications: With R Examples](http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa3/) and it comes in many versions: the "regular" (yellow, printed) version, the blue version and the EZ (green) version.

The blue version is like the yellow version, but it is continuosly updated. The green version requires fewer mathematical prerequisites than the others and should be accessibe to more readers.

Both the blue versions and the green versions are available for free (but I can't find right now a link to the blue version).